# How to make internal processing encoding change to UTF8 in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

Currently in my application the utf8 encoded data is spoiled by internal coding of PHP.

How to make it consistent with utf8?

**EDIT**:To show examples,please tell me how to output the current internal encoding in PHP?

In php.ini I found the following:

```
default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
```

Which means Latin1.

How to change it to utf8,say,what's the iso version of utf8?

Comment: can you please elaborate, and show some examples?

Answer (score 4):

Change it to:

default_charset = "utf-8"

There is no ISO version of UTF-8.

You'll need to be specific with the details since encoding can be mangled at many different areas in your PHP application. 
The common problem areas are:

**Saving and retrieving from DB:**
The database encoding must the same as the strings sent to it from PHP, or you must convert the strings to the DB encoding.

**PHP4's single byte string functions:**
PHP's functions such as strlen(), str_replace() do not produce the correct results on multibyte encodings such as UTF-8, since they operate on single bytes.

**Page encoding:**
Make sure the browser knows you are sending it UTF-8.

Comment: Isn't utf-8 the same as iso-10646-1?
For "PHP4's single byte string functions",you mean replace all those string functions to mb_ functions?

Comment: iso-10646-1, didn't know that. I wouldn't set the configuration to  iso-10646-1 though. Yes, use the mb_functions for PHP4. PHP5 has native support for UTF-8.

Comment: @bucabay - php5 has the same problems as PHP4, there's no "native support"

Answer (score 0):

You can change the character encoding in php file. To change encoding in php page use the following function.

```
$new_value = htmlentities('$old_value',ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

and also you can add the following in the html head section

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I hope this will help to solve your problem.